# th hours day minutes and seconds load as 0 only

Tags: javascript

th hours day minutes and seconds load as 0 only

```
<html
<span id="countdown"></span>

<script>

// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Jan 15, 2016").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Please first correct your html tag, so it has a closing `>`. Also, please make your problem more clear. Where do you get `0` as value?

Comment: is there a question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem ! everything work correctly.

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
var ex_target_date = new Date("Jan 15, 2016").getTime();
var target_date = new Date(2016 , 0 , 15 , 0 , 0 , 0).getTime();// <--- this is preferable

 document.write('<hr>ex_target_date : ' + ex_target_date + '<br>');
 document.write('ex_target_date : ' + target_date + '<hr>');


// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

    // find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
    var current_date = new Date().getTime();
    var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

    // do some time calculations
    days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

    hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
    seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

    minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
    seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

    // format countdown string + set tag value
    countdown.innerHTML = days + "d, " + hours + "h, "
    + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s";  

}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Comment: I agree - can OP check the system date on your computer? Did you change it to January 15?

Comment: I am agreeing with you Anonymous0day... asking the OP to check their system clock

Comment: i have made a modif about date initialisation !